# CS0104 I need help 'Object' is an ambigious reference between 'UnityEngine.Object' and 'object'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> 'Object' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Object' and 'object'

I don't know how to fix it.

This is the code: https://pastebin.com/r68RdqAs

Errors in the following lines:
45; 55; 69; 71; 73; 74; 75; 76; 77; 78; 85;91; 96; 670; 677; 684; 691; 703; 704; 706; 707; 708; 715;

e.g.

```
this.status = Object.FindObjectOfType<Status>();
```

Comment: This question is good enough (if you know Unity) and the answer is both correct and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have both these lines:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
```

Then when you use `Object`, it can't tell if you're referring to `object` (which is a keyword for `System.Object`) or `UnityEngine.Object`. So you need to tell it which one you mean.

For example, instead of this:

```
this.status = Object.FindObjectOfType<Status>();
```

Do this:

```
this.status = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType<Status>();
```

Or you can add an alias for `UnityEngine.Object` with a [`using` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive):

```
using UnityEngine.Object = UnityObject;
```

Which would let you do this:

```
this.status = UnityObject.FindObjectOfType<Status>();
```

Comment: Nice, and with the destroy part?
cant figure that out either..

Comment: It's exactly the same issue.

Comment: May I get an example or something please?

Comment: It doesn't matter what comes after `Object` - this is about the use of `Object` itself. Whatever you do to `Object.FindObjectOfType<Status>()` to make it work, do exactly the same thing to `Object.Destory(...)` to make it work.

Comment: I can't understand :( im sorry but I can't focus idk what is wrong with me

Comment: Did you change your code at all yet?

Comment: Yeah, fixed line 45, but the rest of it I can't get it

Comment: Right, so what did you change on line 45?

Comment: I have added UnityEngine

Comment: Right. So do exactly the same thing in the other places.

Comment: I just add UnityEngine before .Object right?

Comment: Yes, exactly...